# DIsplaying a message in an exception

Tags: c#

I wrote some code testing out a BankAccount and I finished it (for the most part). 
The purpose was me attempting to learn how to throw and try/catch exceptions. For the most part I learned quite a bit. I realize this wasn't an "exceptional" case and if/else statements would have been more appropriate. I am just trying to learn exception handling. 
I am trying to write the exception classes to extend a class to include a new message detailing the error being sent when an exception is thrown.
I read up on what a super class is, or base class in c#, and tried it. It compiles and looks right but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone explain to me why my message in my throw new NegativeDepositException will not show.

What I would like for it to do, is to throw a message instead of me putting a string in MessageBox.Show.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        public class NegativeBalanceException : Exception { }
        public class NegativeWithdrawException : Exception { }
        public class NegativeDepositException : Exception
        {
            public NegativeDepositException() { } // this  doesn't do what I would like for it to do.
            public NegativeDepositException(string message)
                : base(message) { }
        }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class BankAccount
    {
        decimal amount = 300.00m;
        // Declare Delegate Type Object
        public delegate void BankDelegate(decimal oldBalance, decimal newBalance);
        // Create Delegate Type Events 
        public event BankDelegate OnDeposit;
        public event BankDelegate OnWithdraw;

        public void Deposit(decimal a)
        {
            if (a < 0)
                throw new NegativeDepositException(); //"type some message here instead of messagebox below");
            OnDeposit(this.amount, this.amount + a);
            this.amount += a;
        }
        public void Withdraw(decimal a)
        {
            if (a < 0)
                throw new NegativeWithdrawException();
            OnWithdraw(this.amount, this.amount - a);
            this.amount -= a;
            if (this.amount < 0)
                throw new NegativeBalanceException();
        }
    }
    // this is my bank class variable...
    BankAccount account = null;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      account = new BankAccount();
        account.OnDeposit += new BankAccount.BankDelegate(account_OnDeposit);
        account.OnWithdraw += new BankAccount.BankDelegate(account_OnWithdraw);
    }
    private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            var amount = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            try { account.Deposit(amount); }
            catch (NegativeDepositException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot deposit negative amounts");
            }
        }
    }
    private void btnWIthdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var amount = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
        try { account.Withdraw(amount); }
        catch (NegativeBalanceException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot withdraw money that isn't there");
        }
        catch (NegativeWithdrawException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot withdraw negative money");
        }
    }
    void account_OnDeposit(decimal oldBalance, decimal newBalance)
    {
        label4.Text = oldBalance.ToString();
        label5.Text = newBalance.ToString();
    }
    void account_OnWithdraw(decimal oldBalance, decimal newBalance)
    {
        label4.Text = oldBalance.ToString();
        label5.Text = newBalance.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but you're not passing the message when throwing the Exception;

It should be:

```
 if (a < 0)
    throw new NegativeDepositException("Cannot deposit negative amounts");
```

and when catching it you need to call the Message property of the Exception (which is in the Exception base class)

```
    catch (NegativeWithdrawException exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Essentially yes it isn't passing. There were errors with that (exception.Message);, mainly citing I needed references and when I added them it continued on with more errors.